# How to show app icon,app name and version in a group like facebook or twitter in settings bundle?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

How can we add app icon with app name and version in a group like following screenshot

[image: Twitter settings Screenshot]

I have tried following code.But this is showing only version.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>1.0.0</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Version</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>version</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, the Settings bundle is pretty limited in what you can do.